# Vuejs2 print array elements seperated by a line break

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vuejs2, i have a `select`tag where a `person` is choosen, and the properties for the person's address are binded directly in the element.
And i should print out the adress of the choosen `person`
I tried using an array, it is meant to print out the elements seperated by line breaks.

```
{{ 
    [ 
        person.address_1, 
        person.address_2, 
        person.zip_code + ' ' + person.station_city, 
        person.country_name 
    ].join('<br>') 
}}
```

this should print as an example:

```
5 Place Charles Béraudier 
Gare de Lyon Part dieu
69003 LYON
France
```

Somehow the code does not format correctly. And it prints out the code instead of the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `{{ var }}` notation in Vue escapes any HTML. To output raw HTML, you can use `v-html` directive:

```
<div v-html="[ 
    person.address_1, 
    person.address_2, 
    person.zip_code + ' ' + person.station_city, 
    person.country_name 
].join('<br>')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `v-html` because it's dangerous : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

You can instead use the `<pre>` tag : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

So for this you would need a computed method:

```html
<pre>{{ formattedAddress }}</pre>
```

```
computed: {
  formattedAddress () {
    return `${this.person.address_1}\n${this.person.address_2}\n${this.person.zip_code} ${this.person.station_city}\n${this.person.country_name}`
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @BTL for your answer, but Bogdan answer is more convient for me, and i don't have an XSS threat since in my case data cannot be modified by users.
But other users should use yours.